# Speed up rake task by using typhoeus

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So i stumbled across this: https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus

I'm wondering if this is what i need to speed up my rake task

```
Event.all.each do |row|

  begin
  url = urlhere + row.first + row.second
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
  doc.css('.table__row--event').each do |tablerow|
    table = tablerow.css('.table__cell__body--location').css('h4').text
    next unless table == row.eventvenuename
      tablerow.css('.table__cell__body--availability').each do |button|
        buttonurl = button.css('a')[0]['href']
        if buttonurl.include? '/checkout/external'
          else
        row.update(row: buttonurl)
      end
      end
  end
  rescue Faraday::ConnectionFailed
    puts "connection failed"
  next
  end
end
```

I'm wondering if this would speed it up, Or because i'm doing a `.each` it wouldn't?

If it would could you provide an example?

Sam

Comment: it could speed up task but your question is very strange =) you already have a code so just try to use `Typhoeus` and see what it will be looks like.

Comment: Performance is a complex subject... It's really not possible for me to say how much faster it will run with HTTP requests being made in parallel. Try it, and see!

Comment: There are probably some other performance improvements you could make without the gem, too - e.g. Doing `next unless table == row.eventvenuename` seems odd. Why not just skip these iterations by a more intelligent selector than `doc.css('.table__row--event')`? LIkewise, for `buttonurl.include? '/checkout/external'` -- just fine-tune your selector.

Comment: Or, yet *another* possible performance boost: Is `row.first + row.second` always unique? If **not**, then you could cache the results (in a hash) and avoid duplicated HTTP requests.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to reply! just saying try it and see? I've been looking at the documentation and i'm not sure how this won't just make the same request on the row?

Answer (score 0):

If you set up Typhoeus::Hydra to run parallel requests, you might be able to speed up your code, assuming that the `Kernel#open` calls are what's slowing you down. Before you optimize, you might want to run benchmarks to validate this assumption.

If it is true, and parallel requests would speed it up, you would need to restructure your code to load events in batches, build a queue of parallel requests for each batch, and then handle them after they execute. Here's some sketch code.

```
class YourBatchProcessingClass

  def initialize(batch_size: 200)
    @batch_size = batch_size
    @hydra = Typhoeus::Hydra.new(max_concurrency: @batch_size)
  end

  def perform
    # Get an array of records
    Event.find_in_batches(batch_size: @batch_size) do |batch|
      # Store all the requests so we can access their responses later.
      requests = batch.map do |record|
        request = Typhoeus::Request.new(your_url_build_logic(record))
        @hydra.queue request
        request
      end

      @hydra.run # Run requests in parallel

      # Process responses from each request
      requests.each do |request|
        your_response_processing(request.response.body)
      end
    end
  rescue WhateverError => e
    puts e.message
  end

  private

  def your_url_build_logic(event)
    # TODO
  end

  def your_response_processing(response_body)
    # TODO
  end

end

# Run the service by calling this in your Rake task definition
YourBatchProcessingClass.new.perform
```

Ruby *can* be used for pure scripting, but it functions best as an object-oriented language. Decomposing your processing work into clear methods can help clarify your code and help you catch things like Tom Lord mentioned in the comments on your question. Also, instead of wrapping your whole script in a `begin..rescue` block, you can use method-level `rescue`s as in `#perform` above, or just wrap `@hydra.run`.

As a note, `.all.each` is a memory hog, and is thus considered a bad solution to iterating over records: `.all` loads all of the records into memory before iterating over them with `.each`. To save memory, it's better to use `.find_each` or `.find_in_batches`, depending on your use case. See: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html